# Magento 2 not able to load phtml file in email template .html file

Tags: magento2, template, email

I am trying to send an email with dynamic data which is array format.

I have an email template:
`NameSpace/modulename/view/adminhtml/email/email_template.html`

And the phtml file path is: `NameSpace/modulename/view/adminhtml/templates/email/template.phtml`

Using this `{{block type='core/template' area='adminhtml' template='email/replenish.phtml' }}`, I am calling phtml file in the email template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes i got the solution for phtml file loding into html file with following script
`{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='adminhtml' template='Conversion_Replenish::email/replenish.phtml'}}`